# Server returns broken file

Tags: php, nginx, export, attachment

I have a script which taking data from DB and collect it into PHP output cache (ob_start) by printing it. After it flushing and I get prompt to save file. But file not always of needed length. Almost always it have 160 Kb length, but sometimes it have full length 15 Mb. I just ran that script 20 times and 3 times of 20 I got normal file size, in other cases it has same size (160 538 bytes).

Why this could happen?

Short variant of my code:

```
ob_start();
$offset = 0;
$count  = 20000;
while (true) {
    $dataFromMysql = GetMySqlData($count, $offset);
    foreach($dataFromMysql as $data) {
        print implode(';', $data);
    }

    if (!$dataFromMysql || count($dataFromMysql) < $count) {
        break;
    }

    $offset += $count;
}

header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Length: ' . ob_get_length());
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
ob_end_flush();
exit;
```

Site stands on two physical servers. But I asked admin to direct the flow to the main server for that script.

Comment: first move headers to top

Comment: Check max execution time + try sending the file chunked (using HTTP/1.1 header)

Comment: Headers at the top of the script now and added header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: chunked'); but still same problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I beat it!

Here is short variant of working code:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: chunked');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$outputString = '';
$offset = 0;
$count  = 20000;
while (true) {
    $dataFromMysql = GetMySqlData($count, $offset);
    foreach($dataFromMysql as $data) {
        $outputString .= implode(';', $data);
    }

    if (!$dataFromMysql || count($dataFromMysql) < $count) {
        break;
    }

    $offset += $count;
}

$contentLength = strlen($outputString);
header('Content-Length: ' . $contentLength);

$hFile = fopen('php://output', 'wb+');
if ($hFile) {
    for ($i=0; $i<$contentLength; $i++) {
        fwrite($hFile, $this->outputString[$i]);
    }
    fclose($hFile);
}

exit;
```

I don't know why, but it now works! Just because I outputting full collected string by one character (1 byte). I tried to output it by 1Kb (1024 bytes), but it didn't work :(

```
$hFile = fopen('php://output', 'wb+');
if ($hFile) {
    for ($i=0; $i<$contentLength; $i++) {
        fwrite($hFile, $this->outputString[$i]);
    }
    fclose($hFile);
}
```

I hope it will help someone ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ob_* functions you could simply write to a string variable, then you can use strlen() to get the Content-Length and then you print out the full string at the end.

Edit:
What might be more useful is fputcsv(), you could use it to generate a csv file server-side and send it out at the end using readfile().

Comment: I tried to save data into string, php://output, real file, ob_* But nothing of it works properly... thats why I'm here)